# Add domains to NodeJS Express http server on the fly

Tags: node.js, express

I'm hosting multiple domains each running the same node app using Express vhost. I start them all using http.createServer

```
var app = express(); 
require('./app.js')(function(theApp) {

    app.use(express.vhost(domainName1, theApp));
    app.use(express.vhost(domainName2, theApp));
    app.use(express.vhost(domainName3, theApp));
    var d = domain.create();
    d.run(function(){
        http.createServer(app).listen(80);
    }); 
});
```

Is it possible to do the same thing but be able to add new domains to the server on the fly without having to restart the node application? IE pseudo-code:

- Do the above
- Wait for a Domains database record to be added
- Add a new vhost
- Restart necessary things

I want to make sure that users of the existing domains get as little down-time as possible (or even none) whilst the new domain is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Express behavior is to not discriminate based on the `Host` header. The `vhost` middleware adds this behavior. You probably could add more middleware whenever you discover a new domain you want to support… or you could just *not discriminate on the `Host` header in the first place*:

```
var app = express(); 
require('./app.js')(function(theApp) {
    app.use(theApp);
    var d = domain.create();
    d.run(function(){
        http.createServer(app).listen(80);
    }); 
});
```